# When and why do I need to release objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, release

I was curious to know what the real importance of realeasing objects is, and when it should be done. Also, when you change scene, does it automatically release everything, or are they still  in the memory?

Thanks

Comment: If that's the kind of question you'd wish you'd rather not need to know about, then by all means start using ARC (automatic reference counting). See my blog for more info: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/tag/automatic-reference-counting/

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thanks, im wathing the video right now, but I was wondering if ARC is the best solution for all situations. Are there any situations where it would not be wanted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well that depends, you should only release object that you own. You own object that you create via `alloc`, `copy`, `mutableCopy` or `new`. Releasing them when you don't need them any more is always a good idea.

You should start by reading the [memory management documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) apple provides.

But if you are using `ARC` than there is no need for you to release object, since this is determent at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The CCScene on changing will automatically release only it's childs, i mean CCNode subclasses, that you added to it. If you retained any object by code, you must release it in dealloc method

Answer (score 0):

well i am new to objective c but 1 thing i would like to mention is that why bother about allocation or release or retain when apple has provided such an awesome feature called ARC. ARC itself takes care of the memory management issues.
so in my opinion all those developers out der jus do d coding n leave d rest to ARC.

Comment: @akuritsu: for more in-depth info on ARC or any other thing u can always google it out. since dis is not a site where v are supposed to give tutorials. 
BTW since you have asked for more info i will direct you to a tutorial. 
follow the below link to understand how ARC functions.
http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/